# Shortest command to download and execute a file on Windows?

Tags: windows, automation

I am looking for the shortest command that would download a file (http) and execute it on Windows.

We assume that the user executing the command is local Administrator and that you cannot use any tools that are not available by default on Windows.

It must work with: `Windows 7` and `Windows 2008`. Extra kudos if someone gives a solution that also works with Windows XP and Windows 2003.

Reasoning: that for deploying stuff on different Windows machines. Using WMI or other methods is not an option because these are not enabled by default and also because machines can be inside our outside a domain, which makes the problem more complex, especially.

Note: If this cannot be done in a command line, a script will do. Let's assume that the file to be downloaded is located at "http://example.com/setup.exe" and that you want to run it with "-y" parameter after it is downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified http, so using `ftp` command in command line would not be ok? Maybe `cscript` + `VB` then?

To download file:
https://serverfault.com/questions/29707/download-file-from-vbscript

To run file:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run (strHDLocation & "-y")
```

Comment: I hate it but until someone finds a better approach I will accept it.

Comment: Ok, but why do you hate it so much? ;) what would you like better?

Comment: Because it is not a single line command, one that you can call in a batch or bash script. In addition to this you may endup having other problems trying to call a .vbcript script

Comment: Then I believe it's not possible using just windows batch - you'd need some external program, like `wget`

Comment: using an external program is not a problem as long you can do it in one line and the external program is part of default Windows installation (no need for other installs).

Comment: By "external program" I mean "needed to be installed" - they're not part of Windows, unfortunately. You are still able to use `ftp`, if you can arrange things so that you could access files this way